# How to remove hair dye stains on hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood, stain-removal

[image]

I made a stupid mistake of not cleaning hair dye stains from hardwood floor immediately and now it has been almost 3 months. I tried with Clorox regular bleach but it is not working.

Any suggestions on getting rid of these stains from hardwood floor?

Comment: You could try **hair dye remover** (intended for use on previously-dyed hair) but I can't guarantee it will work or won't damage the floor finish.

Comment: Looks like PVC plank which would mean you're SOL. Scrub it hard enough and then it'll be a white spot which is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very lucky, and the wood was sealed well, the dye may just be sitting on top of the floor finish and the right solvent and lots of scrubbing may remove it without damaging the finish.

If you are unlucky, the dye's solvent allowed it to soak into the finish a bit. In which case you may not be able to remove it without partly refinishing the floor.

If you are extremely unlucky and the finish was very worn, some of the due might have gotten through and soaked into the wood. In that case you'd be looking at a much more serious refinishing job to get it all. If this is manufactured flooring, that may be impossible without ruining the surface of the flooring.

If hair color remover is a bleach rather than a solvent, it could create its own staining, or un-staining problem. I'd hesitate to try it unless I knew for certain what was in it.

Frankly, I'd contact the hair dye's manufacturer and ask if they had any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed goof off it cleans it up but not how I would like it to not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try Hydrogen peroxide on a small spot first.  Try rubbing it first. If it seems to be working then try soaking a folded-up bit of kitchen paper towel soaked in it.  You may need to repolish the floor

The other thing that often works for many stains, is baking soda.  Again, try as above.